# How do you pronounce planet Ix?

Tags: dune, pronunciation

In Dune, Ix is the universe's Japan, creating gadgets of varying utility.

How do people in Herbert's universe pronounce the name? Is it "Nine" and the inhabitants are "Nine-ians"? Or is it "Icks" inhabited by "Icksians"?

Comment: You might also want to ask why Wallach IX isn't pronounced Wallach "Icks"

Comment: +1 For "Ix is the universe's Japan"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pronounced as written. Ixian = "*ick-see-ann*"

You can hear a clip of Frank Herbert reading from God Emperor of Dune to get a pronunciation guide

In-universe, the inhabitants of Ix ("*icks*") largely aren't aware that the name of their planet derives from a small joke about the position of their planet in their solar system

> *... They are surface truth. **As well ignore what lies beneath that
>   surface as … as try to understand my birthplanet, Ix, without
>   exploring how we derived our name from the fact that we are the ninth
>   planet of our sun.** No … no. It is not enough to see Dune as a place of
>   savage storms. It is not enough to talk about the threat posed by the
>   gigantic sandworms.*

Answer (score 5):

To add another source to Richard's excellent answer.

The *Lynch* movie *Dune* (1984), produced under Frank Herberts guidance, also establishes the pronounciation of "icks" for IX when a Guild navigator has a nice talk with the Padishah Emperor Shaddam IV. See [here (youtube link)](https://youtu.be/xmRB8QKV5b0?t=3m48s).